# Top level await not working for Node 16.16.0?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am converting my node app to use top level await for connecting to my Redis client but am getting the error "*await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules*".

I do not understand why I am getting this error since I am using Node version 16.16.0 and
top level await should work for Node.js since v14.8??

Why is my code not working?

**Versions used**: NODE v16.16.0, Redis ^4.2.0

**STACK TRACE**

```
at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/app/git/app-node-api/src/index.js:4:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
```

**CODE**

```
const Redis = require("redis")
const util = require(`util`)
const client = Redis.createClient({
  url: process.env.REDIS_CLIENT_PRIMARY,
})

client.on("error", async (err) => console.log("Redis Client Error", err))

await client.connect() // <- THROWS ERROR "await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules"
```

Comment: Slava Knyazev is correct. To get top-level await working the way you're expecting, you'll need to add `"type": "module"` to your package.json file. That will also mean that you'll need to import your modules in ES format: `import { something } from "./somewhere.js"` as opposed to the commonJS format that you're currently using. ES Modules should be the default IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Top-level await is only available in ES modules. You can write a module by using the `mjs` extension instead of `js` or by setting `{ "type": "module" }` in `package.json`.